# MS Access: Question about connecting to back end SQL DB through web server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, odbc, dsn

So is it possible to use microsoft access as a front end for form, query, etc development and connect to SQL Server back end through a web server using a ODBC connection from workstation Data Server Name? What port would this typically use? What is all involved with this type of setup? What difficulties may arise from this setup?

Thanks
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the SQL database is on a web server and you are not talking about calling web services then it is very easy. Access allows you to link tables from any ODBC source and work with them as if they are normal tables (some restrictions apply). If you want to open the tables in code then you can use ADO to open up a connection and then manipulate the data that way.

The easiest way to link the tables is to make a DSN using the program odbcad32.exe which you can find in this folder on XP “C:\WINDOWS\system32” Once you do that you just go into access and link the table using that DSN

Comment: so the Laptops are on a different network from the database server, adn the web server. so i am a novice and am trying to understand this, but i believe the answer to your question is Yes this would call web services...thanks for the help/info

Comment: No, the suggestion here is to NOT use web services and for the most part web services are not going to help you in this scenario at all. The poster is simply suggesting that you use standard ODBC and linked tables to the edition of your database server running on that website.  This is entirely possible and been doing this for years (and it works well).  And you likely consider using DSN less connections. As for the port number, well there is the standard sql server port is 1433. However that port will depend on the config and often web servers don't open their database to the wild internet.

Comment: +1 on the DSN-less connection. I use that method myself but thought it would be easier for the poster to just use a DSN connection to get him up and running. Here is a link to the Microsoft KB article on the subject http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892490. I have modified this slightly as I have a local table of tables and then a table with the connection strings, username and password (Encrypted of course). I then have a sub that loops through that table of table and re links the tables with the connection string, username and password from the other table

Comment: I think most standard commodity-level web hosts will not expose a SQL Server port to the open Internet by default. You're going to need some special configuration or additional services (like a VPN connection).